# SQL Server procedure error - duplicate entries inserted into the table

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I am writing a procedure in SQL Server to insert or update records.

The update part of the code is working fine but when I am executing it for inserting, duplicate entries are inserted into the table.

I created the primary key to avoid this error but after creating that I am not able to insert any single record.

Here is the code :

```
Alter Procedure test_case 
    @id int, 
    @name nvarchar(20)  
AS
    If exists (Select t_id from testing2 where t_id = @id) 
    begin 
        update testing2 
        set t_id = @id, t_name = @name 
        where t_id = @id 
    end 
    else
    begin
        insert into testing2 (t_id, t_name, last_date, hard)
            select 
                @id, @name, convert(date, getdate()), 'null' 
            from test
    end
```

On executing it is showing 2 rows affected

Comment: well, how many rows does the `test` table has?

Comment: if `update` is executed when your `@id` matches with mulitple rows, it updates all those rows.  Without any data visibility, it is hard to solve your problem here

Comment: Table is empty.

Comment: @paemmi - why do you need `from test`.  All your values are direct parameters that can be straight away used in `insert`

Comment: To add on.. the Testing2 table is empty... i tested the update part by normally inserting the values to the table . But i want it to insert with the stored procedure

Comment: use `insert into testing2 (t_id, t_name, last_date, hard) values (@id, @name, convert(date, getdate()), 'null')`

Comment: Thanks for your response. After removing the test from the select statement, insert is working fine for the new records but when I am passing an old record it is also updating as well as inserting a new row for the value passed. Please help me on this new issue.

Comment: You can always debug the procedure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not require test table in the select query

```
       insert into testing2 (t_id, t_name, last_date, hard)
        select 
            @id as t_id, @name as t_name, convert(date, getdate()) as last_date, 'null' as hard
```

is enough

Answer (score 0):

I like to break functionality into smaller parts because it helps me to manage code better.
Maybe this is not a good example since it is pretty simple but I will write it anyway.

```
Create Procedure Testing2_InsertData (
  @id int, 
  @name nvarchar(20)
) As
Set NoCount On

Insert Into testing2 
  (t_id, t_name, last_date, hard)
Values
  ( @id, #name, GetDate(), null )
Go



Create Procedure Testing2_UpdateData (
  @id int, 
  @name nvarchar(20)
) As
Set NoCount On

Update testing2 Set
  t_name = @name --, maybe last_date = GetDate()
Where ( t_id = @id )
Go



Create Procedure Testing2_SaveData (
  @id int, 
  @name nvarchar(20)
) As
Set NoCount On

If ( Exists( Select t_id From testing2 Where ( t_id = @id ) ) )
  Exec Testing2_UpdateData @id, @name
Else
  Exec Testing2_InsertData @id, @name
Go
```